# Study the uniform convergence of a logarithmic sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I proved that the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,+\infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x)=n\ln(1+x/n)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$. Now, in order to study the $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, I noticed that $f_n(0)-f(0)=0$ and that $f_n'(x)-f'(x)<0 \ \ \ \forall \,\, x\in]0,+\infty[$, so $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup(f(x)-f_n(x))=+\infty$ and therefore $f_n$ does not converge uniformly in $[0,+\infty[$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: consider the sequence of functions $g_n(x) = (x^2+1/{n^2})^{1/2}-1/n$. These satify that $g_n(0)=0$ and that $g_n'(x)<f'(x) = 1$, but they uniformly converge to $f(x)$ on $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: I think you may have missed my point, I studied the derivatives in order to remove the absolute value, then the sup is infinity in this case

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{n}: [0,+\infty[\subseteq \mathbf{R}\longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$, defined by $x\mapsto n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$ for all $n\in \mathbf{N}$.

- Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_{n}(x)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{1/n}=x$. So, indeed, $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $f:x\mapsto x$ on $[0,+\infty[$.
- We can see if the the set $\beta_{n}:=\{|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|: x\in [0,+\infty[\subseteq \mathbf{R}\}$ is unbounded.  Notice that $\displaystyle |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=\left|n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)-x\right|=\left|\log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}-\log(e^{x})\right|=\left|\log\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}}{e^{x}}\right)\right|$ but for a natural number $n$ fixed we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=0$, so indeed the set $\beta_{n}$ is unbounded and then $f_{n}$ do not converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,+\infty[\subseteq \mathbf{R}$.

To say that $f_n \to f$ converges uniformly in $[0,+\infty[\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ means geometrically that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $n_0\in \mathbf{N}$ such that the graph of $f_n$ is contained in the $\varepsilon$-radius band of $f$ for all $n>n_0$.

[image]